# How do I pass a get variable through a url with a custom router?

Tags: php, url, parameters, get

I'm making a website using a custom made router. With the current code, I can add a pretty url for example '/contact' to the website. I'm now this far that I need to add a product page. Normally you would have a url like product?product_id=$product_id. But I don't know how I can implement this idea with the current code. The Route class is where is where it adds new urls.

```
class Route
{
    private $_uri = array();
    private $_method = array();

    /*
     * Builds a collection of internal URL's to look for
     * @param type $uri
     */
    public function add($uri, $method = null)
    {
        $this->_uri[] = '/' . trim($uri, '/');

        if($method != null){
            $this->_method[] = $method;
        }
    }

    public function submit()
    {

        $uriGetParam = isset($_GET['uri']) ? '/' . $_GET['uri'] : '/';
        $routeFound = false;
        foreach($this->_uri as $key => $value){
            if(preg_match("#^$value$#",$uriGetParam)){
                if(is_string($this->_method[$key])){
                    $routeFound = true; 
                    $useMethod = $this->_method[$key];
                    new $useMethod();
                }
                else{
                    $routeFound = true; 
                    call_user_func($this->_method[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
        if(!$routeFound){ 
            http_response_code(404);
            require_once 'pages/404.php';
        }
    }
```

And in the index file i actually add routes to the project

```
<?php
  require_once 'classes/route.php';
  require_once 'classes/config.php';
  require_once 'classes/model.php';
  require_once 'functions.php';
  require_once 'classes/validator.php';

$route = new Route();
$db = new Db();
$model = new Model();

$route->add('/', function(){
  require_once 'pages/home.php';
});

$route->add('/product', function(){
  require_once 'pages/product.php';
});

$route->add('/contact', function(){
  require_once 'pages/contact.php';
});

$route->add('/admin', function(){
  require_once 'pages/admin.php';
});

$route->add('/login', function(){
  require_once 'pages/test.php';
});

$route->submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Which framework are you using?
I’m learning CodeIgniter now, what I do there is something like:

the URL for product would be:
application_path/controller/method/id
For product:
application_path/product/insert/1
(Using “1” as an ID example)

I’d have to add a route, in the route file, to specify that after my /method I’ll have an ID. (I believe the way you do it depends on the framework you’re using)

In my controller, my method would receive a parameter. Just like:

```
Public function insert($id){
//code...
}
```

Comment: I'm not using a framework. I created a router just for fun which allowes me to add urls like /contact or /products. But i have a single product page that needs to get specific product data by using the id. In plain php you would do something like product_id=$id but since i'm using htaccess and that custom router, i don't know how to go further.

Comment: You must config your routes to identify that, the number after /product/, for example, is the id. but I only know how to do that with framework, sorry 

Comment: Do you know someone who can help me with this situation? I know a very few people who actually know how to code